# Picasso threads keep running

Tags: android, picasso

How I am supposed to shut down picasso properly?

Example:
I only have 1 activity, and in this activity in onDestroy, I call shutdown() on all picasso instances(I don't use the singleton one).
But, until this activity gets destroyed, Picasso is keeping the device awake(I start the app, use it, press home, leave the phone for the weekend alone, check it on monday, the battery is dead because Picasso kept the phone awake).

These Picasso threads are still running:

-Picasso-Stats

-Picasso-refQue (twice)

-Picasso-Dispatcher (twice)

Why? Are they supposed to?

What's the best practice for shutting it down? In onStop()? And I should keep a list of unfinished downloads that I might want to retry in onResume()?

Comment: If you leave the activity in background then you need to stop everything in onStop or onPause.

Comment: you might want to post it with your code so that people can know exactly what happened.

Comment: But then it's really inconvinient to resume everything if it was cancelled (for example) during download.

Comment: I don't thing Picasso would keep the device awake by itself. Most likely you are submitting new image requests unadvertedly from your activity. In any case, you can shutdown everything in `onStop`. Picasso itself doesn't need much cleanup, you might want to cancel pending requests, or prevent further requests by calling `picasso.shutdown`. But not doing so wont be enough to keep your device awake for a weekend!

Comment: also want to know, how to disable these threads

Comment: Same problem here. Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know default singleton instance in picasso cannot be shutdown,

but i solved problem, in 'picasso.java' file at line : 643

found this code:

```
@Override public void run() {
  Process.setThreadPriority(THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
  while (true) {
    try {
      // Prior to Android 5.0, even when there is no local variable, the result from
      // remove() & obtainMessage() is kept as a stack local variable.
      // We're forcing this reference to be cleared and replaced by looping every second
      // when there is nothing to do.
      // This behavior has been tested and reproduced with heap dumps.
      RequestWeakReference<?> remove =
          (RequestWeakReference<?>) referenceQueue.remove(THREAD_LEAK_CLEANING_MS);
      Message message = handler.obtainMessage();
      if (remove != null) {
        message.what = REQUEST_GCED;
        message.obj = remove.action;
        handler.sendMessage(message);
      } else {
        message.recycle();
      }    
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      break;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      });
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

**while (true)** have high cpu usage, i decided to change it as follows :

```
@Override public void run() {
  Process.setThreadPriority(THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
  while (true) {
    try {
      // Prior to Android 5.0, even when there is no local variable, the result from
      // remove() & obtainMessage() is kept as a stack local variable.
      // We're forcing this reference to be cleared and replaced by looping every second
      // when there is nothing to do.
      // This behavior has been tested and reproduced with heap dumps.
      RequestWeakReference<?> remove =
          (RequestWeakReference<?>) referenceQueue.remove(THREAD_LEAK_CLEANING_MS);
      Message message = handler.obtainMessage();
      if (remove != null) {
        message.what = REQUEST_GCED;
        message.obj = remove.action;
        handler.sendMessage(message);
      } else {
        message.recycle();
      }

      Thread.sleep(2000);//===> call ever 2 sec to decrease cpu pressure.

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      break;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      });
      break;
    }
  }
}
```